# What is the equivalent of BigQuery's 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE' in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In BigQuery StandardSQL if I want to overwrite a table I use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dataset.table 
AS
(SELECT 
      column1,  
       column2 
 FROM dataset.original )
```

How is this done in postgreSQL? I can't find anything despite spending a good bit of time Googling it. At the moment I'm just dropping the table and recreating it.

Comment: [postgresql replace table without losing dependancies](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/80258/188406) might be relevant. But if dropping and recreating the table works fine for you, I'd just go with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not changing the columns added:

```
TRUNCATE dataset.table;
INSERT INTO dataset.table SELECT 
      column1,  
       column2 
 FROM dataset.original;
```

Otherwise you will need to go the `DROP TABLE/CREATE TABLE` route.